# Regex: Parsing between beginning and end of two different Instance Identifiers in JSON

Tags: json, regex

I've been exhaustively searching for a way to search between something like in this case "dog123", and "cat123", so that I'll be able to use an integration platform to remove them as needed. At first I thought it would need to be something along the lines of using \"dog123\"\,[a-z0-9A-Z",_]* and then some other stuff to explain the end boundary, but i'm completely lost at this point. Does anyone have any suggestions? The end result is again to just remove every single line of text between "cat123",

```
   {
        "items": [
            {
                "tableName": "Table0",
                "count": 2,
                "columnNames": [
                    "dog123,
                    "referenceNumber",
                    "account_id",
                    "first",
                    "last",
                    "street",
                    "city",
                    "name",
                    "name",
                    "postalCode",
                    "address",
                    "number",
                    "dob",
                    "lookupName",
                    "address",
                    "lookupName",
                    "lookupName",
                    "lookupName",
                    "lookupName",
                    "awareness_date",
                    "patient_description",
                    "date_of_issue",
                    "lookupName",
                    "cat123",
                    "insertion_site",
                    "lot_number",
```

Comment: Parse it with a proper parser, then iterate over the parsed structure.

Comment: You want to remove everything between `"dog123,` and `"cat123",` is that right ? Which programming language are you using?

Comment: As zerkms says, use a proper parser. There is no way to do this reliably with a regular expression. Let's say your JSON contains a dictionary with keys "dog123" and "cat123". The regex provided will produce broken JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify the programming language, but to replace everything between `"dog123",` and `"cat123"` using `php`, you can try:

```
$new_json = preg_replace('/"dog123",.*"cat123",/sim', '"dog123","cat123",', $old_json);
print $result;
```

---

for `python` use:

```
import re
new_json = re.sub('"dog123",.*"cat123",', '"dog123","cat123",', old_json, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```